# How to reboot with only few services?

Tags: linux, systemd, gnu

Recently I did an experiment. First, I booted my computer normally and launched the game. Then I stopped gdm.service (I'm using GNOME), executed `xinit` command and launched game again. I didn't measure FPS, but the game quality was comparatively higher. I felt difference. Then I began to wonder if I could reboot with minimum number of services needed to run command line. I could just disable or mask all unwanted services and then enable or unmask them, but I'm looking for a more automated solution. One that will only disable them during one reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own custom `.target` unit, that only wants/requires the minimum of services. Then you could use `systemctl isolate custom.target` to switch into the minimized configuration, and `systemctl isolate graphical.target` to return to normal.

To select the desired state at boot time, you could use the boot option `systemd.unit=custom.target`.

Of course you can name it the way you want, it just needs to have the `.target` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Background Linux services are *very* unlikely to affect your game performance while your graphical display manager or window manager may affect your FPS a lot.

Instead of disabling services you could try installing and using a different lighter desktop environment for your games, e.g. IceWM or even a plain X.org session, i.e. TWM + xterm.

Stopping GDM hasn't fixed your performance - **not** using Gnome has.

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve.

But;
You could look into using crontab for automating the enabling/disabling of services.